# Como buscar se há uma palavra dentro de um texto em R

Tags: r, texto

Preciso saber se dentro de um certo texto tem uma palavra específica, por exemplo `fnord`. Até o momento só achei:

```
x<-"fnord: Você não tem nivel de acesso a está informação."
strsplit(x, "[[:punct:] ]")
[[1]]
[1] "fnord"      ""           "Você"       "não"        "tem"        "nivel"      "de"        
[8] "acesso"     "a"          "está"       "informação"
```

Vi algo sobre a função `grep`, mas não consegui entender direito.
E eu preferiria uma resposta do tipo `TRUE` ou `FALSE`.

Comment: `grepl("fnord", x)`. Veja `help("regexp")`. Nota: `grepl` é o `grep` **l**ógico. Além disso, se sabe utilizar padrões como `"[[:punct:] ]"` não vai achar as expressões regulares difíceis de aprender.

Comment: Eu nem sabia que existiam "expressões regulares"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@rui-barradas já deu a resposta nos comentários, esta é só uma elaboração. Primeiro, criemos um exemplo com mais frases.

```
string.vector <- c(
  "gnoll: Você tem acesso total a esta informação.",
  "stack: Você tem acesso parcial a esta informação.",
  "fnord: Você não tem nivel de acesso a esta informação.",
  "fnord: Você poderia ter acesso a esta informação."
)

> string.vector
[1] "gnoll: Você tem acesso total a esta informação."       
[2] "stack: Você tem acesso parcial a esta informação."     
[3] "fnord: Você não tem nivel de acesso a esta informação."
[4] "fnord: Você poderia ter acesso a esta informação."
```

`grep` irá te dar os índices (posições) na qual o padrão que buscar foi encontrado. `grepl` irá te dar VERDADEIRO/FAlSO para todas as posições:

```
> grep('fnord', string.vector)
[1] 3 4

> grepl('fnord', string.vector)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

strsplit gera uma lista com as strings separadas de acordo com o critério que estabeleceu (pontuações e espaços, no caso):

```
split.list <- strsplit(string.vector, "[[:punct:] ]")

> split.list
[[1]]
[1] "gnoll"      ""           "Você"       "tem"        "acesso"    
[6] "total"      "a"          "esta"       "informação"

[[2]]
[1] "stack"      ""           "Você"       "tem"        "acesso"    
[6] "parcial"    "a"          "esta"       "informação"

[[3]]
[1] "fnord"      ""           "Você"       "não"        "tem"       
[6] "nivel"      "de"         "acesso"     "a"          "esta"      
[11] "informação"

[[4]]
[1] "fnord"      ""           "Você"       "poderia"    "ter"       
[6] "acesso"     "a"          "esta"       "informação"
```

Aplicar grep e grepl aqui te dará o mesmo resultado, porque está sendo indicado quais itens da lista possuem a chave de busca:

```
> grep('fnord', split.list)
[1] 3 4

> grepl('fnord', split.list)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Você pode usar lapply para aplicar grep/grepl à cada elemento da lista

```
> lapply(split.list, grep, pattern = 'fnord')
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1

> lapply(split.list, grepl, pattern = 'fnord')
[[1]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[3]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[4]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

O pacote `stringr` tem funções amigáveis para trabalhar com strings de texto. Cheque a [vinheta dele sobre expressões regulares](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html) (em inglês).